# Insert instead of from select and inserted data

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm having trouble creating a trigger in a SQLite DB on a view that inserts values into 2 different tables and then inserts the "ID" values from those tables and values from the inserted data into a 3rd table. So basic idea is ....

```
CREATE TABLE [TBL1] (ID UNIQUE INT AUTOINCREMENT,VAL1);
CREATE TABLE [TBL2] (ID UNIQUE INT AUTOINCREMENT,VAL2);
CREATE TABLE [TBL3] (ID1 INT,ID2 INT,VAL3);
CREATE VIEW [v_TBL3] AS 
  SELECT (TBL1.VAL1,TBL2.VAL2,TBL3.VAL3) 
  FROM TBL3 
  INNER JOIN TBL1 ON TBL3.ID1 = TBL1.ID
  INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL3.ID2 = TBL2.ID;

========== heres the problem ==========
CREATE TRIGGER [t_TBL3_INSERT] INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v_TBL3
  BEGIN
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO [TBL1] (VAL1) VALUES NEW.VAL1;
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO [TBL2] (VAL2) VALUES NEW.VAL2;

    INSERT INTO [TBL3] (ID1,ID2,v_TBL3.VAL3) 
      SELECT (TBL1.ID,TBL2.ID,VAL3)
      FROM TBL1,TBL2,v_TBL3
      WHERE TBL1.VAL1 = v_TBL3.VAL1 AND TBL2.VAL2 = v_TBL3.VAL2;
  END;
```

I've looked on around on the net but I'm not finding quite what I need to get me there. Can someone help me get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention what your problem is, but when using [proper SQL syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html), your schema would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, VAL1);
CREATE TABLE TBL2 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, VAL2);
CREATE TABLE TBL3 (ID1 INT, ID2 INT, VAL3);
CREATE VIEW v_TBL3 AS 
  SELECT TBL1.VAL1, TBL2.VAL2, TBL3.VAL3
  FROM TBL3 
  INNER JOIN TBL1 ON TBL3.ID1 = TBL1.ID
  INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL3.ID2 = TBL2.ID;

CREATE TRIGGER t_TBL3_INSERT
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v_TBL3
BEGIN
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TBL1 (VAL1) VALUES (NEW.VAL1);
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TBL2 (VAL2) VALUES (NEW.VAL2);

    INSERT INTO TBL3 (ID1, ID2, VAL3) 
      SELECT TBL1.ID, TBL2.ID, VAL3
      FROM TBL1, TBL2, v_TBL3
      WHERE TBL1.VAL1 = v_TBL3.VAL1 AND TBL2.VAL2 = v_TBL3.VAL2;
END;
```

Comment: The problem I was having ended up being in the ()'s in the trigger. I'd never written a trigger before the too I was using was not giving me very useful error messages. I went back and checked but some of the sites I was referencing are apparently using improper SQL syntax so thats why I was getting confused. Just goes to show why even your off the cuff examples should be accurate. Never know who will use them later. Thanks for the help.